# Enviar arquivos para o MySQL no Blob

Tags: mysql, delphi, firebird

bom dia.

Alguém sabe como posso enviar arquivos exe e csv para o MySQL usando o Delphi?

Não achei muito conteúdo sobre isso. Preciso guardar arquivos CSV na tabela mas quando faço a importação pelo teste abaixo o tamanho do arquivo é muito menor que o original.

```
imgfoto.Picture.LoadFromFile('C:\1\1.jpeg');

imagem := Tmemorystream.Create;

imgfoto.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(imagem);

FDQuery1.Open;

FDQuery1.First;

if FDQuery1.Locate('LJ_NOME', 'AAAAAAAA', []) then

begin

FDQuery1.Edit;

TBlobField(FDQuery1.FieldByName('LJ_BLOB')).LoadFromStream(imagem);

end;
```

Eu tentei converter o CSV e o EXE para JPEG e enviar via stream, ele não reconhece por não ser imagem. Testei via memo, mas ele carrega a primeira linha apenas.

Como faço para enviar os arquivos para o MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize "LoadFromFile" do campo. Abaixo um exemplo da forma que utilizada.

Considerando a seguinte tabela:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `arquivos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `arquivo` BLOB NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```pascal
FDQuery1.Insert;
FDQuery1arquivo.LoadFromFile('<Caminho para o arquivo>');
FDQuery1.Post;
```

[Código de exemplo](https://gist.github.com/gguimp/5777eac5d09143f97501e70c83e187a1)